# Disabling ranges of Unicode characters in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea meant for plain text that users sometimes copy and paste special characters into. It becomes a problem when emoticons are used, because it's material we then need to include in PDF files.

For instance: ❤️

```
&#10084;
```

Now my question is, how could I go about identifying such characters and removing them with Javascript as the form is validated? I don't want to be too restrictive, as many languages are allowed (Russian, Arabic, etc.). Only those symbols would need to be excluded.

Thank you

Comment: Use the `pattern` attribute.

Comment: That's indeed a possibility, but I'm looking for the regex that would filter emoticons without filtering foreign languages

Comment: What do you mean by “those symbols”? As soon as you have defined your problem exactly enough, you have solved it more than 50% – the rest is just writing a regexp or simple code that runs checks against character ranges.

Comment: We just had a customer '' enter his name and address in what is apparently the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block. I hope this isn't a trend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript. The problem is that emoticons are in the Supplementary plane. That does not allow you to use a normal character range; instead you need to work with "surrogate pairs", along the lines of

```
/\ud83d[\ude00-\ude4f]/
```

The link above has additional information on how to find and treat emoticon characters in other Unicode ranges.